# PHP Delete newline before insert MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've been searching for days to get this fixed:

I cannot get newlines removed out of a string.
All i tried:"

```
str_replace(PHP_EOL, '[br]',($_POST['replytext']))
$data['message'] = nl2br($_POST['replytext']);
$data['message'] = str_replace('<br />', '[br]', $_POST['replytext']);
```

the nl2br for example will convert a newline to `<br />`, BUT it will ALSO add a new line. Anyone know how to strip all enters? OF EVEN BETTER: replace them with '[br]'?

Example code to delete newlines from (this has been nl2br'ed):

```
<br />
<br />
testt
```

I know how to preg replace (for example) the `<br />` code. It's just the ENTER you see after `<br />`.

I really hope someone has the solution, since I've been trying to get this working for days already, my head is about to explode.

**EDIT:**

Example post which could be added into a text area:

```
This is my reply. blabla

Some new lines, and now the quoted text below:

[quote=DaSP date=2017-08-07 17:42:37]dsaasdasd[br][br]asdasd[br][br]asd[br]asd[br][br][quote=DaSP date=2017-08-07 17:42:28]asd[br][br][quote=DaSP date=2017-08-07 17:16:06][br][br]fg[/quote][/quote][/quote]
```

Best regards,
Ronnie

Comment: $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));

Comment: Can you post `$_POST['replytext']`?

Comment: @OrlandoP. Will this also delete spaces? I tries s+ before (some code but without trim). Trim only didnt do it.

Comment: `\s+` is one or more whitespace, not specific to new lines.

Comment: @RonnieOosting yes the regex is accounting for whitespace between words and after them. Trim only takes care of the whitespace after the string not in between it.

Comment: @OrlandoP. I need something that wont delete spaces, it need to replace the new lines with [br]. The new lines which are saved when a user press 'Enter' in a textarea, those new lines.

Comment: Post a real input example. Is it `\n\ntestt`?

Comment: @chris85 This is my reply. blabla

Some new lines, and now the quoted text below:

[quote=DaSP date=2017-08-07 17:42:37]dsaasdasd[br][br]asdasd[br][br]asd[br]asd[br][br][quote=DaSP date=2017-08-07 17:42:28]asd[br][br][quote=DaSP date=2017-08-07 17:16:06][br][br]fg[/quote][/quote][/quote]

Comment: This is copy pasted. As you can see the ENTER button is not displayed. Ill add it to the original post

Comment: @chris85 a real input is added. Its the same as when you create a topic at stackoverflow and you put ENTER's in the textarea to create a new line.

Comment: Why does `trim` not work? https://3v4l.org/NDhXN or perhaps `ltrim`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

Comment: Good suggestion! Ill try ltrim, second.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks chris for all your help, see Amit his answer, that one worked. I saw his reaction and tried that before ltrim, so im not sure if ltrim works. Thanks for al your help man, i appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK use the following function then. This could probably be done with preg_replace too, but here it is with str_replace.

```
function replaceWithBr($str)
{
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = str_replace("\r\n", "[br]", $str); 
    $str = str_replace("\r", "[br]", $str); 
    $str = str_replace("\n", "[br]", $str);  
    return $str;
}
$text = "hello
test

more lines,
Thanks,
";

echo $text."<br >";
echo replaceWithBr($text)."<br >";
```

Comment: What about the newlines between the text? A user could post for example: (Hi User,(ENTER) How are you? (ENTER ENTER) @OP Hi to you too). This is just random, as you can notice haha. Those ENTER's in a textarea need to be replaced with [br] instead of a new line in MySQL.

Comment: nl2br should take care of adding <br> before those new lines. Do you want to remove new lines altogether?

Comment: Hi Amit, All newlines need to be replaced with [br]. All new lines you create by pressing the ENTER button in a textarea

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your comments. Check if that works.

Comment: Amit, thank you!!!!!! It works! Finally. Thanks a lot. Marked yours as the answer

Comment: Won't this be the same as `nl2br(trim($str));`? or then swap the `<br>` with `[br]`.

Answer (score -2):

use [strip_tags](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp)

```
echo strip_tags("Hello <b><i>world!</i></b>");
```

**EDIT**

as suggested `strip_tags` wont work on new line in that case you could use `regex`

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

Comment: This won't strip new lines, if they are new lines.

Comment: Hi Arun, strip_tags looks awesome for security endings, but is not working for new lines in a textarea (ENTER button)